# r11 bind error, inspite of $port in exec command

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

```
2013-03-04T06:47:21+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-03-04T06:47:21+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
**2013-03-04T06:47:22+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `exec unicorn -p 6662 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`**
2013-03-04T06:47:23+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-03-04T06:47:23.679109 #2]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
2013-03-04T06:47:24+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-03-04T06:47:24+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-03-04T06:47:25+00:00 app[web.1]:         This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
2013-03-04T06:47:25+00:00 app[web.1]:         cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
2013-03-04T06:47:25+00:00 app[web.1]:         Called from: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.
2013-03-04T06:47:25+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-04T06:47:25+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-04T06:47:25+00:00 app[web.1]:         provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
2013-03-04T06:47:25+00:00 app[web.1]:         SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
2013-03-04T06:47:25+00:00 app[web.1]:         future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.
2013-03-04T06:47:27+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-03-04T06:47:27.469450 #2]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:6662 fd=8
2013-03-04T06:47:27+00:00 app[web.1]: Disconnected from ActiveRecord
2013-03-04T06:47:27+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port 55101, should be 6662 (see environment variable PORT)
2013-03-04T06:47:27+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-03-04T06:47:28+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-03-04T06:47:28+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-03-04T06:47:31+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ivms/13? host=murmuring-plains-5992.herokuapp.com fwd="202.157.93.2" dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

so exec started with correct port 6662, but end up with wrong port. this is happening with every 
heroku ps:restart or heroku restart.

what am I missing.

environment: 
rails3
ruby 193
heroku cedar stack

Comment: my procfile: web: exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your Procfile?  Heroku will dynamically assign a PORT variable for each dyno. This value may change. over restarts.  So your web process type should read the PORT variable value, and use it.

See the example on this [article about unicorn](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn#procfile), which does it like this:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

Comment: my procfile: web: exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb

Comment: Starting process with command `exec unicorn -p 6662 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`**

Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port 55101, should be 6662 (see environment

so it started with correct port but somehow ended up with wrong port

Comment: I'm going to guess that your config file for unicorn is binding to ports with something like a listen, perhaps.  Try the sample config [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn).